# Is it possible to listen for console input from a C# Windows Application?

Tags: c#, console-application, stdin, .net-8.0, chrome-native-messaging

I have a .NET Core 3.0 Windows application that was interfacing with Chrome native-messaging stdin, however after .NET 8 migration, the application no longer has console stdin access. (Note: it was also WinExe even back in Core 3.0, it wasn't set to console application)

The following snippet in .NET 8, it would return a `NullStream`:

```
Stream stdin = Console.OpenStandardInput(); // NullStream in .NET 8
stdin.Read(lengthBytes, 0, lengthBytes.Length);
```

Unless, I manually allocate a `Console` at the beginning of `Main`, the above snippet would give me `WindowsConsoleStream`:

```
AllocConsole();
```

I've been trying to find out what was the major changes between .NET Core 3.0 to .NET 8 that would cause this and that how to get the code to work without success. It looks like Microsoft completely stripped out `Console` capability from `Windows Application`?

A couple of questions:

- How can I get back/simulate the old behavior?
- Possible to have a Windows Applications while having stdin access?
- Is `Console.OpenStandardInput` the only way to get stdin?

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Windows Console and Terminal Ecosystem Roadmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/ecosystem-roadmap) and [Classic Console APIs versus Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/classic-vs-vt)

Comment: @user246821 Do you have any examples on how to read from stdin with the new virtual terminal? Those documentation does not really point to anything specific about transitioning from the classic to the new.

Comment: No unfortunately. You'll have to do some research to figure it out. Did you read the information in the pink box? The pink box contains some URLs.